# What is the name of the baboons that live in Saudi Arabia

Tags: species-identification

In Saudi Arabia there are a lot of baboons in the mountain area. I would like to know what's the name of this specific baboons so I can read about them more:

[image: baboons]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like [Hamadryas Baboons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamadryas_baboon) (*Papio hamadryas*). They also fit the geographical location.

[image]